# Sidebar toggle not working after redirecting to another route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

On my nextjs website, after login it redirect to home page. On homepage, sidebar toggle is working perfectly. Also, navigation menu toggle works fine. Once I click on another menu then after redirection, sidebar toggle and menu toggle stops working. I have to reload the page manually to get it working again.

I have already searched for this issue but haven't found anything which can help me.

Here's my website -- https://totb-dev.herokuapp.com/ and login with test / test.

I want sidebar and navigation menu toggle works fine even after redirection.

Comment: After login, go to Customers -> View to go to another route. Once you go to another page, toggle functionality will stop working.

Comment: Tried it on chrome and it's working for me. I went to Customers->View and Restaurants->View, and was able to slide the menu in and out no problem. (No refreshing needed)

Comment: There was a issue creating build. Works fine now.